# Binding Controls in ASP.NET FormView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

I have what I think is a very basic question, only problem is that try as I might to figure it out and searching hi and low in the net I'm still short of the answer I need, hopefully some jedi on here can help me out.

Basically I have an access 07 DB that I am going to both select from and insert into from a form view. I want a drop down list to be popluated on load with a unique ID number from one of the tables in my DB (ClientNames), first name and last name as well as living area (textboxes) to be populated based on the selectedItem, and the user to fill out the rest of information.

I then want the whole form to be inserted into a seperate table (Section1), inculding the data queried from the ClientNames table.

What I have working is populating the drop down and inserting all of the fields into my desired table. What I can't figure out is populating the first name, last name, and living area fields on something like a selectedIndexChanged event or via another data source in the formview. I think at this point I've confused myself with research and just need a definte direction to head in, but I'm new to binding data in ASP.NET and the rules it imposes. So we'll see.

I'll gladly provide any snippets of code for my datasource or formview control if you all would like to see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the OnSelectedIndexChanged event on the Dropdown to call a function which pulls all the data that you need.  Once you've gotten the data bind it to a Repeater control ( http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp ) that contains all of your fields etc.

Hope this helps!